# I need to direct my dbms_output in a mail

Tags: oracle, email, plsql

As a part of my daily operations I need to:

- run a procedure,
- get the output in a notepad,
- copy some part in mail and send it to business.

If I could send mail from database, then it would save some good time.
Is it possible? If yes, can anyone share some sample codes?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Oracle 10g or later you can also use [`UTL_MAIL`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_mail.htm) (which is basically a wrapper on top of UTL_SMTP).

```
UTL_MAIL.SEND (
   sender     => 'me@host'
   recipients => 'you@host',
   subject    => 'test email',
   message    => 'Hello!');
```

But note - from the docs:

> `UTL_MAIL` is not installed by default
>   because of the `SMTP_OUT_SERVER`
>   configuration requirement and the
>   security exposure this involves. In
>   installing `UTL_MAIL`, you should take
>   steps to prevent the port defined by
>   `SMTP_OUT_SERVER` being swamped by
>   data transmissions.
>
> You must both install `UTL_MAIL` and
>   define the `SMTP_OUT_SERVER`.
>
> To install UTL_MAIL:
>
> ```
> sqlplus sys/<pwd>
> SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlmail.sql
> SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/prvtmail.plb
> ```
>
> You define the `SMTP_OUT_SERVER`
>   parameter in the init.ora rdbms
>   initialization file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UTL_SMTP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_smtp.htm#ARPLS074) to directly create mails from your plsql procedure. ([example code](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_smtp.htm#i1006675)) Caveat: the database server must be able to access the mail server; in some organisations, firewall rules prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides some packages which you can use to send mail
Following link talks about it

[link text](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL)http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL

Answer (score 0):

This wikiarticle should help you: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL

It is for Oracle 8 but it should work also with 10 or higher.

Edit: Dam to slow ^^